# PHP error al comprimir archivos y bajarlos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un problema para hacer funcionar un código que tengo de PHP que siempre ha estado funcionando.

El código recoge los archivos de una carpeta, la copia en una segunda carpeta, comprime los archivos de la  segunda carpeta y lo baja al usuario, todo ello al pulsar un botón submit.

Llevo revisando el código y buscando en internet el posible fallo, pero veo todo correcto y desconozco el fallo.

Agradecería si alguien con más idea en php pudiese ayudar a encontrar ese fallo.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

````
    if (isset($_POST['copy_all'])) {

  $ano = $_POST['ano'];
  echo $ano;
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  $query = "SELECT * FROM rentas where ano = '2020'";
  $search_result_renta = filterTable($query); 
  $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result_renta);

  #While para copiar
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result_renta)):
    $doc = $row['doc'];
    if ($doc != ""){
      $copy_from = '../../upload/renta'.$doc;
      $copy_to = '../../zip_renta/'.$doc;
      copy($copy_from,$copy_to);
    }

  endwhile;
  //comprimimos
  $folder = @scandir('../../zip_renta/');
  if(count($folder)>0){
    comprimir($copy_to);
  }

  //Borramos todos los archivos de la carpeta renta.
 // delete_files();
}

//funcion para comprimir
function comprimir($dir) {
  
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $filename = 'Para_Renta.zip';
  $dir = "../../zip_renta/";
  $dir_open=opendir($dir);


  $files = array();
  while ($current = readdir($dir_open)){
    if( $current != "." && $current != "..") {
      if(is_dir($dir.$current)) {
         echo $dir.$current.'/';
      } else {        
        $files[] = $current;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE){
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n"); // puedes lanzar una excepción
  }

  // USO del array $files no verifiqué si lo recogiste correctamente
  foreach($files as $file){
    $localfile = basename($file);
    $zip->addfile($dir.$file, $localfile); // las demás opciones por defecto
  }

  $zip->close();
  // Mensajes opcionales de depuración antes de cerrar el zip
  //echo "Archivos incluidos: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
  //echo "estado:" . $zip->status . "\n";
  //Movemos el zip a la carpeta de renta
  $filePath = '../../zip_renta/'.$filename;
  rename ($filename,$filePath);

  $zip_file = basename($filename);

  if(is_file($filePath)){
    // Define headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // Read the file
    readfile($filePath);
    exit;

  }

}
//Funcion para eliminar los archivos bajados en la carpeta renta.
/*function delete_files(){
  $files = glob('../../zip_renta/*'); //obtenemos todos los nombres de los ficheros
  foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); //elimino el fichero
  }
}*/

function filterTable($query){
  include ("../conn/connection.php");
  $filter_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  return $filter_result;
}```
````

Comment: Y el error cual es ???

Comment: No funciona. No veo error pero no copia los archivos, ni comprime, ni baja nada

Comment: Y no te arroja ningún error ??

Comment: Nada, le doy al botón y no hace nada. Compruebo si copia algún archivo y no hace nada. Sin embargo las carpetas están correctas.

 $doc = $row['doc'];
    if ($doc != ""){
      $copy_from = '../../upload/renta'.$doc;
      $copy_to = '../../zip_renta/'.$doc;
      copy($copy_from,$copy_to);
    }

Comment: Entonces debugea la funcion.. imprimiendo con var_dump() las variables mientras se van generando

Comment: No tengo mucha idea. Podrías ponerme un ejemplo. He puesto después de declarar la variable $doc, var_dump($doc) pero no veo ningún output

Comment: No tienes idea de como imprimir datos ¿¿??

Comment: ya lo hice. echo var_dump() no soy experto. Finalmente he conseguido que copie. El problema estaba en el botón por mucho que le daba no funcionaba, por lo que lo coloque después de una query y funcionó.

Me da este fallo:
Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /volume1/web/control/pages/rentas/rentas.php on line 93

La dos carpetas involucradas tienen permisos recursivos 777.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido que copie perfectamente. Pero no se genera el archivo zip. Lo he creado manualmente, y una vez lo encuentra lo baja, aunque dice que no es un archivo comprimido.

Expongo la función de comprimir. Que la veo bien, pero no veo el fallo.

```
function comprimir($dir) {
  
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $filename = 'Para_Renta.zip';
  $dir = "../../zip_renta/";
  $dir_open=opendir($dir);


  $files = array();
  while ($current = readdir($dir_open)){
    if( $current != "." && $current != "..") {
      if(is_dir($dir.$current)) {
         echo $dir.$current.'/';
      } else {        
        $files[] = $current;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE){
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n"); // puedes lanzar una excepción
  }

  // USO del array $files no verifiqué si lo recogiste correctamente
  foreach($files as $file){
    $localfile = basename($file);
    $zip->addfile($dir.$file, $localfile); // las demás opciones por defecto
  }

  $zip->close();
  // Mensajes opcionales de depuración antes de cerrar el zip
  //echo "Archivos incluidos: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
  //echo "estado:" . $zip->status . "\n";
  //Movemos el zip a la carpeta de renta
  $filePath = '../../zip_renta/'.$filename;
  rename ($filename,$filePath);

  $zip_file = basename($filename);

  if(is_file($filePath)){
    // Define headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // Read the file
    readfile($filePath);
    exit;

  }
```